# SQLALchemy "after_insert" doesn't update target object fields

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model (see code below) on which I want to execute a function after an object is inserted that will update one of the object's fields. I'm using the *after_insert* Mapper Event to do this.

I've confirmed that the *after_insert* properly calls the *event_extract_audio_text()* handler, and the *target* is getting updated with the correct *audio_text* value. However, once the event handler finishes executing, the text value is not set for the object in the database.

**Code**

```
# Event handler
def event_extract_audio_text(mapper, connect, target):

    # Extract text from audio file
    audio_text = compute_text_from_audio_file(target.filename)

    # Update the 'text' field with extracted text
    target.audio_text = audio_text

# Model
class SoundsRaw(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'soundsraw'

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(255))
    audio_text = db.Column(db.Text())

# Event listener
event.listen(SoundsRaw, 'after_insert', event_extract_audio_text)
```

I've also tried calling *db.session.commit()* to try to update the object with the text value, but then I get the following stack trace:

```
File "/Users/alexmarse/.virtualenvs/techmuseum/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 219, in _assert_active
raise sa_exc.ResourceClosedError(closed_msg)

ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed
```

Any ideas?

**Software versions**

SQLAlchemy 0.9.4
Flask 0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy 1.0

Comment: Hey @ducu, see the answer I just posted.

I think that what solves the ResourceClosedError is the `create_db_session()` line in the second block of code, so maybe you can use that in your Mapper Event code and see how that works. I'm curious.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I found a similar question elsewhere (can't remember), I'll post the solution below, it worked for me and I'd say it's a little cleaner than your solution below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving this by ditching the Mapper Event approach and using Flask's [Signalling Support](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/signals/) instead.

Basically, you can register "signals" on your model, which are essentially callback functions that are called whenever a specific kind of event happens. In my case, the event is an "update" on my model.

To configure the signals, I added this method to my `app.py` file:

```
def on_models_committed(sender, changes):
    """Handler for model change signals"""
    for model, change in changes:
        if change == 'insert' and hasattr(model, '__commit_insert__'):
            model.__commit_insert__()
        if change == 'update' and hasattr(model, '__commit_update__'):
            model.__commit_update__()
        if change == 'delete' and hasattr(model, '__commit_delete__'):
            model.__commit_delete__()
```

Then, on my model, I added this function to handle the update event:

```
 # Event methods
def __commit_update__(self):

    # create a new db session, which avoids the ResourceClosedError
    session = create_db_session()

    from techmuseum.modules.sensors.models import SoundsRaw
    # Get the SoundsRaw record by uuid (self contains the object being updated, 
    # but we can't just update/commit self -- we'd get a ResourceClosedError)
    sound = session.query(SoundsRaw).filter_by(uuid=self.uuid).first()

    # Extract text from audio file
    audio_text = compute_text_from_audio_file(sound)

    # Update the 'text' field of the sound
    sound.text = audio_text

    # Commit the update to the sound
    session.add(sound)
    session.commit()

def create_db_session():
    # create a new Session
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

    psql_url = app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']
    some_engine = create_engine(psql_url)
  
    # create a configured "Session" class
    session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)

    return session
```

Answer (score 21):

The thing with 'after_insert' kind of handlers is to use the connection directly. Here's how I did it:

```
class Link(db.Model):
    "News link data."

    __tablename__ = 'news_links'

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    slug = db.Column(db.String, unique=True) #, nullable=False 

    url = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    image_url = db.Column(db.String)
    description = db.Column(db.String)

@db.event.listens_for(Link, "after_insert")
def after_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    link_table = Link.__table__
    if target.slug is None:
        connection.execute(
            link_table.update().
            where(link_table.c.id==target.id).
            values(slug=slugify(target.id))
        )
```

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.after_insert) are not very good, but here, I found the similar question which led me to this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13765857/45712