# How to attach the @db.event.listens_for(Model, "after_insert") to all models in my models.py file without writting everyone seperately

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249045/sqlalchemy-how-to-use-events-listens-for-in-flask-sqlalchemy-sqlalchemy/45147957#45147957) I was able to monitor my models.

Now I want to create a general listener for all models that for start will simply log that event. I do not want to write out this event 20 times (lets say i have 20 models) I want a way to attach the db.something to it. And whenever flask-sqlalchemy inserts (or whatever i specify) I will the printout.

## Relevant Info:

[SQLALCHEMY: how to use @events.listens_for in flask_sqlalchemy-SQLalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249045/sqlalchemy-how-to-use-events-listens-for-in-flask-sqlalchemy-sqlalchemy/45147957#45147957)