# flask sqlalchemy UniqueConstraint with foreignkey attribute

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, unique-constraint

I have an app I am building with Flask that contains models for Projects and Plates, where Plates have Project as a foreignkey.

Each project has a year, given as an integer (so 17 for 2017); and each plate has a number and a name, constructed from the plate.project.year and plate.number. For example, Plate 106 from a project done this year would have the name '17-0106'. I would like this name to be unique.

Here are my models:

```
class Project(Model):
    __tablename__   = 'projects'
    id              = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name            = Column(String(64),unique=True)
    year            = Column(Integer,default=datetime.now().year-2000)

class Plate(Model):
    __tablename__   = 'plates'
    id              = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    number          = Column(Integer)
    project_id      = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('projects.id'))
    project         = relationship('Project',backref=backref('plates',cascade='all, delete-orphan'))

    @property
    def name(self):
        return str(self.project.year) + '-' + str(self.number).zfill(4)
```

My first idea was to make the number unique amongst the plates that have the same project.year attribute, so I have tried variations on 
`__table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('project.year', 'number', name='_year_number_uc'),)`, but this needs to access the other table.

Is there a way to do this in the database? Or, failing that, an `__init__` method that checks for uniqueness of either the number/project.year combination, or the name property?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to your problem. For example, you can de-normalize `project.year-number` combination and store it as a separate `Plate` field. Then you can put a unique key on it. The question is how you're going to maintain that value. The two obvious options are triggers (assuming your DB supports triggers and you're ok to use them) or sqla Events, see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#

Both solutions won't emit an extra SELECT query. Which I believe is important for you.

your question is somewhat similar to [Can SQLAlchemy events be used to update a denormalized data cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693872/can-sqlalchemy-events-be-used-to-update-a-denormalized-data-cache)