# save an instance of object in two models simultaneously

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to create a route that will track all the history of a product. I have created a model for the `product` and a similar model for `producthistory`. Now, whenever I am creating an object I want it to be saved in the `product` table as well as the `producthistory` table. The only difference in both the tables is the id field. The `producttable` contains the id of the product & the `producthistorytable` has an id field of the `historytable` as well as the id of the product. I want to filter with the id of the product for further usage of the data. How can I insert the product object in the producthistory table along with the id of the product that was created at that point in time?

Here is the models:

```
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    product_url= Column(String)
    current_price= Column(Integer)
    updated_at= Column(String)
    created_at= Column(String)
    target_price= Column(Integer)
    product_name= Column(String)


class ProductHistory(Base):
    __tablename__ = "producthistory"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    product_id = Column(Integer)
    product_url= Column(String)
    current_price= Column(Integer)
    updated_at= Column(String)
    created_at= Column(String)
    target_price= Column(Integer)
    product_name= Column(String)
```

here is the logic for creating product:

```
@app.post('/createproducts/')
def createproducts(request: Product, db:Session = Depends(get_db)):
    product = models.Product(
        product_url= request.product_url,
        current_price= request.current_price,
        updated_at= request.updated_at,
        created_at= request.created_at,
        target_price= request.target_price,
        product_name= request.product_name
    )
    db.add(product)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(product)
    return product
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can SQLAlchemy events be used to update a denormalized data cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693872/can-sqlalchemy-events-be-used-to-update-a-denormalized-data-cache)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `events`, which are basically hooks, which are performed after certain actions with the DB. As far as I understand, you need an `after_insert` hook: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.after_insert

In your case it would be:

```
from sqlalchemy import event


@event.listens_for(Product, 'after_insert')
def receive_after_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    # target is the created instance of Product

    # ... create an instance of ProductHistory from target...
```